# Angularjs - requesting PHP script from own server returns 403

Tags: php, angularjs, http, get

I'm using AngularJS for my website. I wan't to make a GET request to my mysql database using php. I've created a simple php script

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM table");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
        $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"name":"'  . $rs["name"] . '",';
}    
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

when I request this php file with angularJs http.get the response is 403 forbidden. My AngularJS code:

```
getScript: function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/app/scripts/script.php',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        return $http(req);
    }
```

As you can see I get 403 even tho it's from same server. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I got 403 due to this line in my .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getScript: function () {
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/app/scripts/script.php',
    };
    return $http(req);
}
```

Try not to customize the Request header. This Should solve the 403 Forbidden Issue.

Comment: Maybe I might be wrong but most probably the Issue you are getting is because when you are trying to make a server call your browser is making an preflight OPTIONS request which is getting denied.(not sure if GET makes an prflight). The issue might be with the request/response header which server is rejecting. Hope this info might help

Comment: I answered my own question. It was due to Options FollowSymLinks in my htaccess file