# How to connect my sql data base in angular?

Tags: angular

This is my HTML.

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <form (submit)="onSubmit()" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="names" [(ngModel)]="profileForm.name" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="email" [(ngModel)]="profileForm.email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2" name="password" [(ngModel)]="profileForm.password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2" name="repassword" [(ngModel)]="profileForm.repassword" placeholder="Re-Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mb-1" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <label class="checkbox float-left">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
      Remember me
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="float-right">Need help?</a>
  </form>
```

This is `ts` file:

```js
onSubmit() {
  console.warn(this.profileForm);
  this.http.post('./script.php', this.profileForm).subscribe(function(data) {
  });
}
```

Comment: you cant connect to db from agular directly. Based on your code you are trying to call php script. So you have to call sql databse from that script.

Comment: You need to connect to the database within your php script

Comment: yes i did php script.

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");$name=$_POST['name'];$email=$_POST['email'];$password=$_POST['password'];$repassword=$_POST['repassword'];$query = "INSERT into emp_details (emp_name,emp_email,emp_password,emp_repassword) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$repassword')";mysqli_query($con, $query);echo true;

Comment: i am geeting error:POST http://localhost:4200/script.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: your local angular dev server can't run php, in your setup you would have to provide the script.php within your angular app, and thats not possible. When you want a thing like this go for that: Node.js + express.js and Build a REST Api. That's the way it works today. If you want PHP then go for the Slim-Framework. It's small and fast to build.

Comment: Angular use apis to connect to the server side. Never connect directly.

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull It is very possible to include php scripts in your angular APP. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your php files on  server lets take example as xampp server which is running on your local PC place your file in htdocs folder , connect your database in that php file and start your xampp server so your link will be `http://localhost/script.php`.

Pass this link in your angular httpModule as

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/script.php').subscribe((result) => {
console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: erroe like this(Failed to load http://localhost/script.php: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.)

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem as I had once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593433/angularjs-requesting-php-script-from-own-server-returns-403

Comment: Also remember to place this in the top of your PHP script:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: add in your headers, header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");